# How to Include a C++ file from a public directory on a web server directly to the IDE?

Tags: c++, http, include, cdn

**Overview:**
In web programming, external code files doesn't have to be in the same directory or even in the same computer. For example I could use:

```
<script src="file.js"></script>
```

to include file.js from the same directory. Or

```
<script src="https://www.domain.com/file.js"></script>
```

to include file.js from a web server.

Currently, I'm writing a C++ library on GitHub (it's just a group of lightweight C++ files) and I want it to be available for everyone to directly include it even without manually saving it; I want the precompiler to manage the temporary downloading.
Unfortunately, the below code doesn't work:

```
#include "https://www.domain.com/file.h"
```

**Note:** The question is a "*How to?*" not "*Is it possible?*" and if you believe it is unachievable, I assume you can not prove your answer; So, please leave it unanswered. Else, all solutions are appreciated

Comment: The pre-compiler does not do this.  I'm not really sure how relevant downloading live source code is tbh. I can see why it is necessary for *interpreted/VM* languages like `Javascript` or `Java` because the code runs *live* when the page/app is viewed. `C++` needs to be compiled into a platform dependent binary where the source code no longer exists (and is not needed). Perhaps [Github submodules](https://github.com/blog/2104-working-with-submodules) will suit your needs?

Comment: This is what build systems are for, that make sure the code is accessible to the compiler before it runs. All build systems that I am aware of download the code to a local directory. This has one huge advantage over your proposed solution, too: Clients of your code continue to compile, even if you decide to take your GitHub repository offline. You are really asking about a solution that has no advantages over existing solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Let’s put aside the question if this is a good idea or not. Is it at all possible? This is what the standard says about the #include directive:

**C++14 Standard, 16.2/2 [cpp.include]**

> A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> #include < h-char-sequence> new-line
>
> searches a sequence of implementation-deﬁned places for a header identiﬁed uniquely by the speciﬁed
> sequence between the < and > delimiters, and causes the replacement of that directive by the entire contents
> of the header. How the places are speciﬁed or the header identiﬁed is implementation-deﬁned.

The “h-char sequence” allows characters from the source character set:

**2.3 [lex.charset]**

> a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
>
> A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
>
> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
>
> _ { } [ ] # ( ) < > % : ; . ? * + - / ^ & | ∼ ! = , \ " ’

Nothing in this wording says anything about where included files have to be located physically. Also all characters required for useful URIs are allowed.

**The problem**

No C++ compiler I am aware of and certainly none of the major three (Clang, GCC, MSVC) implements this feature.

**Todo**

Relying on additional tools is not going to work. In that case just cloning the repository in question is too easy and familiar a task.

So, here is what you’ll have to do:

- Get the source code to the relevant compilers, implement URI support for #include (don’t forget caching or compile times will be glacial) and get it accepted as an official feature of the respective compiler.
- Implement support in the relevant build systems. For a start I suggest at least make, CMake and GNU Autotools.
- Do lots of marketing to convince the C++ community to use this feature.